# Can't ping my own machine

Tags: networking, rhel

I was installing httpd on my RHEL8 box and all went fine. I decided to test a website then and accidentally ran `iptables -F`. Next thing I know, I can't even ping my own ip address. It can't resolve ARP requests, I'm only able to ping `127.0.0.1` and other machines on the LAN but they can't ping me back, probably because of ARP failure. I tried stopping iptables and firewalld services and restarting them but the problem seems unaffected. On my dlink router, I can't see my machine listed in the LAN, however I can use the internet and ssh which is strange. What should I do?

Edit: problem has eerily resolved itself after a reboot.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro your comment makes no sense but fine. PROBLEM IS RESOLVED NOW.

Comment: My comment means this is a rushed questions before OP experiencing anything, and reboot should have been tried before writing this. OPs are expected to investigate and do a fair effort debugging *their problems*.

Answer (score 1):

Try bringing the interfaces down and then back up. Also you can add a default policy for iptables (e.g. `iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT`, `iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT`)

Comment: Reboot fixed it. :/

Comment: RHEL8 actually uses nftables and not iptables (assuming you're using the default firewalld).  So you'd need to use the appropriate `nft` commands.